# Is there a javascript (jquery) slider that limits the values independently of the display values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I wish to have a slider that is from 0-100 but that is only selectable from 0-75 (for example)

An example look would be something like this, with the slider restricted from entering the coloured region

[image: Sample limited slider]

Clearly I would like to be able to set the max, min, limit and value of the slider...

As far as I can see the jquery UI Slider does not allow this out of the box. I expect it is possible to extend the basic behaviour but I would need a very clear hand holding to make that work!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `slide` event of slider plugin which is triggered on every mouse move during slide. Use `ui.value` to obtain the value of the current handle and check for the max limit and return false. Returning `false` from this callback prevents the slide.

```
$(".selector").slider({
   slide: function(event, ui) { 
       if(ui.value > 75){//Note the value of ui.value is between 0 to 99
          return false;
       }
   }
});
```

For the background color of the slider you can easily achieve it through css.